# Issue checking input type in Pyton 2.7 vs Python 3

Tags: python

I need to re-use a script I wrote in Python 3.10 using Python 2.7; when I change the interpreter to 2.7, script below errors with following message: TypeError: unbound method CheckInput() must be called with Elem instance as first argument (got int instance instead)

Trying to resolve this for hours but I'm a beginner and am definitely missing something. Aim of the program is to add a few values as user input and later on print them out. Code below:

```
class Elem():
    Elem_count = 0

    def CheckInput(input):
        try:
            # Convert it into integer
            val = int(input)
        except ValueError:
            try:
                # Convert it into float
                val = float(input)
            except ValueError:
                print("You have entered a string, please use numbers!")

    def Add_Elem(self):
        if Elem.Elem_count == 0:
            print('Enter first Elem info:')
            self.width = input('width: ')
            Elem.CheckInput(self.width)
            self.height = input('Height: ')
            Elem.CheckInput(self.height)
            self.depth = input('depth: ')
            Elem.CheckInput(self.depth)
        else:
            print('Enter second Elem info:')
            self.width = input('width: ')
            Elem.CheckInput(self.width)
            self.height = input('Height: ')
            Elem.CheckInput(self.height)
            self.depth = input('depth: ')
            Elem.CheckInput(self.depth)

        Elem.Elem_count += 1
        if Elem.Elem_count > 2:
            exit

    def Display_Elem(self):
        print('\n')
        if Elem.Elem_count == 0:
            print('Element ')
            print('width: ' + self.width)
            print('Height: ' + self.height)
            print('Depth: ' + self.depth)
        else:
            print('Element ')
            print('width: ' + self.width)
            print('Height: ' + self.height)
            print('Depth: ' + self.depth)


def main():
    First_Elem = Elem()
    Second_Elem = Elem()
    First_Elem.Add_Elem()
    Second_Elem.Add_Elem()

    print ("Elements added:")
    First_Elem.Display_Elem()
    Second_Elem.Display_Elem()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: you need to give checkInput the static marking or give the self parameter

Comment: Are you using an old-style-class on purpose?

Comment: Python 2 reached [End-of-Life 2 years ago](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/). Python 3.10 is very different with a *lot* of breaking changes. Why are you trying to use 2.7 instead of Python 3, especially if you're a beginner? Backporting code like this is something advanced users will try hard to avoid. You can have both Python 2 and Python 3 in separate environments on the same machine

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It is true that using Python 2 should never be the first choice. But the OP did say the point was that they needed to take a Python 3 script and run it in a Python 2 environment. Assuming that is an invariant constraint, this is valid, and should be answered in that vein.

Comment: On Python 2 you shouldn't use `input` but `raw_input`. `input` in Python 2 behaves as if you do `eval(input())` in Python 3 and we all try to avoid `eval`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
def CheckInput(input):
```

For a normal class method, you'll have a definition like this:

```
def my_method(self, some_parameter):
```

The `self` here refers to the class. While you *can* pass in some other class, the behavior quickly becomes undefined. Your `TypeError` points to this, though: `CheckInput() must be called with Elem instance as first argument (got int instance instead)`.

This means an `int` was passed - which is likely the parameter you meant. All you need is this:

```
def CheckInput(self, candidate_input):
    try:
        val = int(candidate_input)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            val = float(candidate_input)
        except ValueError:
            print(f"Could not convert '{candidate_input}' to a number!")
    return val
```

Note the change of `input` to `candidate_input` to avoid builtin name collision, and the use of the candidate input in the output string to allow the user to understand what was happening with bad input.

Also, it's likely that you want to return the value that you have - though it's not great design to have a function that returns one of two types of numbers.

Comment: I know this will be deleted soon enough but thanks for explaining thoroughly and not judging my noob code! Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To me the easiest fix would be to remove the checkinput method from your elem class ; it is useless for it to be in the class because it doesn't use the attributes of the class.

Also, you shouldn't name a variable "input" as it is the name of a builtin in both Python 2 and Python 3.

```
def CheckInput(data):
    try:
        # Convert it into integer
        val = int(data)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            # Convert it into float
            val = float(data)
        except ValueError:
            print("You have entered a string, please use numbers!")

class Elem():
    Elem_count = 0

    def Add_Elem(self):
        if Elem.Elem_count == 0:
            print('Enter first Elem info:')
            self.width = input('width: ')
            CheckInput(self.width)
            self.height = input('Height: ')
            CheckInput(self.height)
            self.depth = input('depth: ')
            CheckInput(self.depth)
        else:
            print('Enter second Elem info:')
            self.width = input('width: ')
            CheckInput(self.width)
            self.height = input('Height: ')
            CheckInput(self.height)
            self.depth = input('depth: ')
            CheckInput(self.depth)

        Elem.Elem_count += 1
        if Elem.Elem_count > 2:
            exit

    def Display_Elem(self):
        print('\n')
        if Elem.Elem_count == 0:
            print('Element ')
            print('width: ' + self.width)
            print('Height: ' + self.height)
            print('Depth: ' + self.depth)
        else:
            print('Element ')
            print('width: ' + self.width)
            print('Height: ' + self.height)
            print('Depth: ' + self.depth)
```